# missing dependencies for check_mk on ubuntu (omd-1.20) php5 and perl5

Tags: ubuntu, check-mk

I'm following the install/setup instructions which are available on both the check_mk and DigitalOcean sites to setup monitoring based on a Ubuntu server. However I am getting errors that several dependencies are missing after installing via `dpkg -i omd-1.20.wheezy.amd64.deb`. I've manualy downloaded and installed serveral packages, downloading from www.ubuntuupdates.org, and I'm now stuck with the following missing dependencies.

```
omd-1.20 : Depends: libperl5.14 but it is not installable
        Depends: php5 but it is not installable
        Depends: php5-cgi but it is not installable
        Depends: php5-cli but it is not installable
        Depends: php5-gd but it is not installable
        Depends: php5-mcrypt but it is not installable
        Depends: php5-sqlite but it is not installable
```

If I use `apt-get -f install` only removes the uninstalled `omd-1.20 (0.whezzy)` software, and not installing the missing dependents. The remaining packages will not install as there are not the newest.

Is there any way to resolve the missing packages? Or will I need to uninstall the current perl and php package and replace it with a older package?

FYI Server is running:

```
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

Comment: Any luck on this issue? I have had the same issue on Ubuntu 16.04.
Seems like the install also does not like the latest versions

Comment: I haven't gotten to played around with this too much as I ended up trying to update & modify one of the existing monitors then setting up a new server. 
The next thing I've found is that there is a new release for 16.04 from the check_mk site. Replace the download link with this file:
    wget https://mathias-kettner.de/support/1.4.0p11/check-mk-raw-1.4.0p11_0.xenial_amd64.deb
The check_mk guide is ok, just includes notes for REHL & SLES, so you need to do some careful reading.